# How to install dill in IPython?

Tags: serialization, parallel-processing, ipython, anaconda, dill

Right at the outset, I tried `conda install dill`, and `conda` was not able to find it on the internet.

Then I downloaded both `.tgz` and `.zip` files in my default IPython directory from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill

After which I tried the following commands:
`conda install dill-0.2b1.zip`
`conda install "C:\<rest_of_the_complete_path>\dill-0.2b1.zip"`
and likewise for `.tgz`. All four attempts yielded the error:
`No packages found matching:`

What is it that I am doing wrong? I am trying to repeat the examples given on the following link:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/minrk/5241793

**Edit 1:** I had installed `dill` on my system by running the `.exe` file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill. This step installed `dill` on my system python (`C:\Python27`) but not on my Anaconda Python. I am assuming that these two pythons are separate since I can import the usual modules (say `numpy` for instance) on both — the python I access through `cmd` and the one I access through my IPython notebooks — but I can import `dill` only on the python I accesses through `cmd` and not in my IPython notebooks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read the quick start guide for Anaconda ([link](https://store.continuum.io/static/img/Anaconda-Quickstart.pdf)) which describes how to install packages not available in the Continuum Analytics Repository. Accordingly I went to [binstar.org](http://binstar.org) and searched for `dill`.

The following versions were available for Windows, of which I downloaded the file `win-32\dill-0.2b1-py27_0.tar.bz2`.
https://binstar.org/dhirschfeld/dill/0.2b1/files

Then I went to the directory where the file was downloaded and executed the following command:
`conda install win-32-dill-0.2b1-py27_0.tar.bz2`

I checked the package availability using the command `conda list` and it seems that `dill` is now installed for my IPython notebooks.

Comment: If you find a package on binstar, you can install it with conda by just adding `-c binstarusername` to the install command (in this case, `conda install -c dhirschfeld dill`).

Answer (score 3):

If conda doesn't install it, it just means that it's not yet in the Continuum Anaconda repository.  You can just do `pip install dill`, and that should work fine with Anaconda.

If `pip` isn't working for you, I have gone ahead and created a conda package for dill and uploaded it to my http://binstar.org channel.  You can install via:

`conda install -c pwang dill`

Comment: I tried `conda install -c pwang dill` but I still get the same error: `Error: No packages found matching: dill`. In my original question, I installed `dill` from the `.exe` file available on the same link. But I was under the impression that my Anaconda python installation is different than my python on `C:\Python27`. For example I can import numpy on both, the command prompt python and in IPython notebook, but I can import dill only on python accessed through my command prompt. I took this to mean that the Anaconda python environment is using a different python than in my `C:\Python27` dir.

Comment: @PeterWang you only built it for OS X.